# Probability of getting even number of consecutive heads followed by a tail in a series of coin tosses

Tags: self-learning, binomial-distribution

Assume a fair coin is tossed $n$ times. I am looking for the probability that the sequence starts with an even number of consecutive heads followed by a tail outcome? I assuming that this means something along lines of summing over binomial distributions, but not really sure here -any specific ideas?

For example in the case of $n=3$:
$$ TTT,HTT,THT,HHT$$
Then the following outcome fulfill the requirements:
$TTT, HHT$

Comment: Hint:  forget the tail at the end, for the moment.  What's the probability that there were evenly many Heads in the first sequence of tosses?  (work it out for a few lengths, and I expect you will see the pattern).

Comment: Thanks, I come so far: Let $x$ be an even number. Then the probability that they were evenly many heads in the first sequence of tosses is $(\frac{1}{2})^x$. Because this events are independent (right?), we can simply take the sum: $\sum_{x \in \{0,2,4,\dots,n\}} (\frac{1}{2})^x$. And then multiply this with $\frac{1}{2}$ for the tail at the end?

Comment: Work examples!  Suppose you have two tosses.   The possible sequences are $HH,HT, TH, TT$.  In exactly two of these we have an even number of Heads so the answer is $\frac 12$, not $\frac 14$ as your formula would give.  Now, do it for three tosses.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Since $0$ is also an even number, always half the cases fulfill the requirement anyway, correct? So the final formula would any string starting with an even number of heads would be : $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{x \in \{2,4, \dots, n} (\frac{1}{2}^k)$. Accounting for the tail at the end: $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{x \in \{2,4, \dots, n-1\}} (\frac{1}{2})^k \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear what is being asked.  The "consecutive" part doesn't appear in the body of the question, only in the title.  What does it mean?  Do you only consider things like $H^{2n}T$ or is something like $TT$? good?  After all, the starting block, $T$, ends with $0$ Heads and $0$ is even.

Comment: To clarify the question, I suggest editing your post to work it out completely for sequences of length $3$.  There are only $8$ such, since we require that they end in $T$ there are only $4$:  $TTT,HTT, THT, HHT$.  Which of those meet your conditions?

Comment: It is consecutive - I edited the question

Comment: Why doesn't $HTH$ work?  The $HT$ initial block ends with $0$ Heads and $0$ is even.

Comment: I think the problem simply isn't clear.  I initially read it as requiring that you had an initial block with an even number of Heads, and then a Tail at the end, but that ignores the "consecutive" requirement, which I don't understand at all.